# fetch values from form and save in different rows of a table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a form through which i can enter values and save them in database

code of form is

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var sampleTags ;

    $("#myTags").tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags,
        afterTagAdded:function(){      
          $('[name="tags"]').val($("#myTags").tagit("assignedTags"));
            //alert( $('[name="tags"]').val());
        }
    });
});

</script>

<form action="insert.php">
 <input name="tags" id="myTags" >
  <button class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

code of insert.php page

```
$tag = $_POST['tags'];
echo $tag;
```

it gives me an o/p that looks like this

```
first,second,third
```

I want to remove the commas from above o/p and insert each one of them in separate row of table. can anyone please tel how i can separate the above o/p

Comment: `explode(',', $tag);` there you go - try learning PHP basisc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode` and using `for loop` insert in database

```
$tags = explode(",", $_POST['tags']);// convert in array break by comma
foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    // your insert query 
}
```